# Topology induced by uniformity (open and closed)

Tags: uniform-spaces

If V is an open (closed) in product topology X$\times$X that induced by uniformity , then $V(x) $ is open (closed) in $X$ ?

Comment: What the means of topology that induced by uniformity?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in X$ and let define the function
\begin{align}
&\sigma_x:X\to X\times X&
&y\mapsto (x,y)
\end{align}
Note that $\sigma_x$ is continuous, for if $\pi_1,\pi_2:X\times X\rightrightarrows X$ denote the canonical projections, then 
\begin{align}
&(\pi_1\circ\sigma_x)(y)=x&
&(\pi_2\circ\sigma_x)(y)=y
\end{align}
are both continuous functions, hence $\sigma_x$ is continuous by [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Properties) of product topology.
Then
$$V(x)=\{y\in X:(x,y)\in V\}=\sigma_x^{-1}[V]$$
which is open (closed) as $V$ is open (closed) in $X\times X$, by continuity of $\sigma_x$.
Note that this holds for every topology on $X$ (not necessarily induced by an uniformity).

Comment: @AhmedAlKhuzai: I add a proof of continuity in the answer.